# LM2917 draws too much current

Tags: power-supply, converter, texas-instruments

I built a prototype of a frequency-to-voltage converter using a [LM2917](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf) following *exactly* the "Minimum Component Tachometer Diagram" example schematic - just to play a bit and understand how it works.

It happens the IC draws too much current, and without limitation it will burn in a while. I checked several time my breadboard and seems ok.

To exclude any error, given a new IC I connected pin 6 to +12V and pin 8 to 0V and **nothing else**. Even in this case the behavior is the same.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I can accept my circuit is wrong, but why I can't just power the IC using pin 6 and 8?

Comment: Did you purchase more than one LM2917?  Try the second one, perhaps the first one is defective.

Comment: Pics, or it didn't happen ...

Comment: Measurments and schematics

Comment: @plasmahh they said they are using the exact test circuit from the linked datasheet.

Comment: The schematic is the one on the first page the datasheet, as said. As said, I tried with different units. Same behavior.

Comment: @passerby that is almost always not the case

Comment: @PlasmaHH I can assure I used the same circuit. I'm sorry if you don't trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the Zener Option of the chip .Use a feed resister of say 470 ohm from say 12V and then check chip voltage .

Comment: The LM2917, which is what the OP suggests using IS with the Zener. The LM2907 has no Zener.

Comment: Got it. My fault was to understand the clause "Using Zener Regulated Options (LM2917)" as an *option*.